# When can a community blog become "official"?

Tags: support, blog-overflow

On the [IT Security Stack Exchange Blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/), the [About page](http://security.blogoverflow.com/about/) says:

> This is the (currently) unofficial blog for the IT Security Stack Exchange site.

Other BlogOverflow sites either do not appear to have an About page at all, or have a similar message.  The only exception I've seen so far is [the one for English Language & Usage](http://english.blogoverflow.com/about/).  Theirs neither specifies official nor unofficial.

The [IT Security Stack Exchange website](http://security.stackexchange.com) has been [out of beta](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/security-stack-exchange-graduated-today/) for [8 months](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/it-security) now.  [The blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/) is just [slightly older](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/we-are-live-with-the-security-stack-exchange-blog/).

At what point can we remove the "(currently) unofficial" note from our About page, and/or replace it with "official"?

Comment: Fixed that for you! Hopefully my wording meets with SEI approval :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks.  I was about to edit it myself earlier, but figured I should ask for SEI's blessing first.